# If vectors $m + s + l = 0$, then $m \times s = s \times l$

Tags: linear-algebra

If vectors $m + s + l = 0$, then $m \times s = s \times l $

True or false, if true show it if false show an example.

I assume true:

So I have let vectors $u\|v$, defined by $u = cv$

The angle between $u$ and $v$ is $\theta = 0$ therefore $u\times v$ = $\|u\|\|v\|\sin \theta n=0$,

Thus rendering $u \times  v = v \times u $

so I set up,

$m + s = cl$

$l + s = cm$

$m + l = cs$

where, $c = -1 $

I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Write $l=-s-m$ and compute $s\times l.$

Comment: So that will give me, m x s = s x -m

Comment: Now, using that $s\times m=-m\times s$ you have that both vectors are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Take the expression $m+s+l=0$ and cross multiply $s$ on both sides..